# C# - TFS 2010 work item validation before saving

Tags: validation, tfs, save, workitem

we have a project using Microsoft Team Foundation libraries connected to TFS 2010.
Our TFS projects was based on Agile 5.0 template. So there are many transitions in projects.

My question is can we do transition validation on state change before saving work items?
I have errors when I try to validate state change without saving.

For example, in transition you allow:

## "" to "Active"

## "Active" to "Closed"

Then you do following:
1. You create a new bug work item.
2. Change state to "Active".
3. Do validation but don't save. --> OK
4. Change state to "Closed".
5. Do validation. --> Failed.

This means you have to save before do further validation. But I don't want to save anything until I'm sure all the state change is OK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to save between state changes. There are transitions and other 'triggers' that trigger on save, which also need to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Since a TFS Work Item has a number of triggers (both on the client and on the server) that trigger on field changes and state transitions it is important to save when one of these important fields change. The Status and Reason field is one of these important fields, especially since it normally drives the state machine that is behind these work items.

So unfortunately, there is some validation before save (mostly on input formats), but there needs to be some on the server as well. From the UI there is no way to trigger the serverside validation through another means than by saving. And there certainly isn't a way to have it execute the rules and transtions without saving the workitem to the server.

If this is important to you I suggest you file a request on the [Visual Studio User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).